# Parameters to communicate between car node and standard host in omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet, veins-lte

I want to communicate between a car node and standard host node. I'm using veins_inet car node. when I run my simulation, alot of parameters are asked e.g. analomodel,x- axis, y axis etc.

1. What parameters should I insert in my ini file.?
2. What should be application type of my server node (standard host)?

##############################My .ned file#######################

```
package testingFOG;

import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.ethernet.Eth100M;
import inet.node.inet.AdhocHost;
import inet.node.inet.Router;
import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
import inet.node.inet.WirelessHost;
import inet.node.wireless.AccessPoint;
import inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.contract.IIntegratedVisualizer;
import org.car2x.veins.nodes.Car;


network testingFOG
{
    @display("bgb=500,300");
    submodules:
        visualizer: <default("IntegratedCanvasVisualizer")> like IIntegratedVisualizer if hasVisualizer() {
            parameters:
                @display("p=36,34");
        }
        configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                assignDisjunctSubnetAddresses = false;
                @display("p=36,83");
        }
        radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {
            parameters:
                @display("p=34,134");
        }
        //endNode: WirelessHost {  //wirelessHost1
        //    parameters:
        //        @display("p=246,111");
        //}
        serverNode: StandardHost {//wiredHost1
            parameters:
                @display("p=400,147;i=device/server");
        }
        //  wiredHost2: StandardHost {
        //      parameters:
        //          @display("p=412,70");
        //  }
        //  router: Router {
        //      parameters:
        //          @display("p=296,69");
        //  }
        AP: AccessPoint {
            parameters:
                @display("p=351,86");
        }
        vehicularNode: Car {
            @display("p=239,198");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        //accessPoint.ethg++ <--> Eth100M <--> router.ethg++;
        serverNode.ethg++ <--> Eth100M <--> AP.ethg++;
       // wiredHost2.ethg++ <--> Eth100M <--> router.ethg++;
}
```

################################My .ini file###############################

```
[General]
network = testingFOG
sim-time-limit = 400s
tkenv-plugin-path = ../../../etc/plugins

**.addDefaultRoutes = false

**.*Node.numUdpApps = 2

**.*Node.udpApp[0].typename = "UDPEchoApp"
**.*Node.udpApp[0].localPort = 1000

**.serverNode.udpApp[*].typename = "UDPBasicApp"
**.vehicularNode.applType= "TraCIDemo11p"
**.serverNode.udpApp[1].destAddresses = "vehicularNode"
**.vehicularNode.udpApp[1].destAddresses = "serverNode"
**.*Node.udpApp[1..].destPort = 1000
**.*Node.udpApp[1..].messageLength = 100B
**.*Node.udpApp[1..].sendInterval = 1s
**.*Node.udpApp[1..].stopTime = 300s

**.initialZ = 0m
```

Comment: Please consider splitting your double-question into two separate ones. It makes questions (and answers) easier to find (and answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .ini file source mode, Go to the console tabs and find the NED parameter tab. It has all available parameters for the modules you have.

[image: These are the parameters]

Comment: and my sesond part of this question is What should be application type of my server node (standard host)?